# How to predict a sequence from random input sequence.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have $6$ sequences $S_1$, $S_2$, $\ldots$, $S_6$, with each sequence containing $60$ data points made of the numbers $\{0,1,2\}$. e.g. $S_1 = [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, \ldots, 0, 0, 0, 1]$. These numbers are randomly placed with $1$ occurring with probability $0.25$ and $2$ occurring with probability $0.15$.

How can I predict the the next sequence $S_7$, such that, if I choose $4$ index points in the predicted sequence, they are $\{1\}$'s?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the probabilities of 1 and 2 (and thus 0), why can't you just use those to generate the seventh sequence?  If all we know are the probabilities, you can't really predict what any sequence will be.  Are your assuming some sort of dependency relating one sequence to previous sequences? Perhaps you can explain a bit more about the motivation behind your question.

Comment: Hi Randy,
Thank you for reply. The problem is predictions of sports betting. Consider on given slip of Football bets, $\{0\}$ is event: one or both teams don't score goals, $\{1\}$ is  both teams score goals and one team wins, and $\{2\}$ is event both teams score goals and its a draw.
The sequences are known outcomes of 60 different matches. I want to predict for a given day, which four teams can be a $\{1\}$.
Additional : probability distribution.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ZpH4IFVEqKYkFJeGxVWXNUZDQ/view?usp=sharing)
x axis: winning probability
y axis: number of matches won